# Visual Studio C# MSBuild.ILMerge.Task problem with The assembly is not marked as containing only managed code

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild, visual-studio-2017

I have Solution with 2 projects like:

- MainDLL
- LibraryDLL

I'd like to merge LibraryDLL inside MainDLL. My application require to import only one single file as plugin.
I downloaded NUGet Packacged:

- ILMerge
- MSBuild.ILMerge.Task

After setting up, when I press build I am receiving following error:

```
ILMerge.Merge: The assembly 'ChilkatDotNet4' is not marked as containing only managed code.
(Consider using the /zeroPeKind option -- but read the documentation first!)
```

I am not using it directly and not need it but its proparbly refrenced by other referenced dll inside both projects (I dont need to include it because application already has it).
How to avoid this problem?
I have tried to setup flag:

```
<!-- See ILMerge documentation -->
<ILMergeAllowZeroPeKind></ILMergeAllowZeroPeKind>
```

To true or false but nothing changes

Comment: any other options? I dont have those c++ project its external lib?

Comment: I think your LibraryDLL is a c++ native library project. Sorry for that I did not describe it in detail. You can add `/zeroPeKind` in your pre build event where I think you run `ilmerge.exe`.

Comment: Like `ilmerge.exe /target:xxxx  /zeroPeKind ..................`

Comment: Hi ,any update for this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working with /zeroPeKind was unsuccessful for me (doesn't mean its wrong way).
I can't also rebuild this native c++ library, because it comes from external provider.

After checking
https://github.com/emerbrito/ILMerge-MSBuild-Task/wiki

> Merge Assemblies With Copy Local = True

I have changed all other References property setting
Copy Local to false.

I left Copy Local = true only for referenced my shared project library which I wanted to merge with my main project.

Answer (score 1):

> Visual Studio C# MSBuild.ILMerge.Task problem with The assembly is not
> marked as containing only managed code

I think your **LibraryDLL** is a c++ native dynamic library project and ILMerge cannot handle with assemblies containing native code.

You must either extract the dll at runtime prior to use, or ship the dll.

**Suggestion**

**1)** I think you have written a pre-build event or post-build event to run this command, so in your command, please add `/zeroPeKind`.

Like `ilmerge /target:xxxx  /zeroPeKind /out:xxxxx   xxxxxxxxx`

**2)** Besides, you could also try [this workaround(use DllImport)](https://weblogs.asp.net/ralfw/single-assembly-deployment-of-managed-and-unmanaged-code) to troubleshoot your issue.